# Pulp Python - How to define a constraint with different indexes of variables

Tags: linear-programming, python, pulp

I am new to modeling LP with Pulp in Python and I need some help with defining a constraint with multiple variables with different indexes. Please see below.

1. The constraint is defined on A, B, C indexes.
2. `Start_Inv` and `End_Inv` variables are again defined on A, B, C indexes.
3. `Production` variable is defined on A, B, C, D indexes.

I want `Production` variable to be summed by A, B, C and enter the constraint.

Below is what I wrote and of course it doesn't work.

```
for A, B, C in Start_Inv_DF.index:

    model += Start_Inv[(A, B, C)] + Production[(A, B, C, D)] == End_Inv[(A, B, C)]
```

Is there an easy way to model this? Probably, I need a coefficient to do "SUM `Production` group by A, B, C", can you please advise how to create one?

Adding more details. 1/13/2022

I have tried lpSUM and it works for two indexes but not for three or more. Can you please see what I am doing wrong?

1. This 2 indexes case works.

```
import pandas as pd 
import pulp as plp

tuples1 = [('DE', 'Apple'),
          ('DE', 'Orange'),
          ('PA', 'Apple'),
          ('PA', 'Orange')]

index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1, names=["Location", "Product"])
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Count A': [12., 70., 30., 20.], 'Count B': [12., 70., 30., 20.]}, index=index1)

Production1 = plp.LpVariable.dicts("Production1",
                              ((Location, Product) for Location, Product in DF1.index),
                              lowBound=0,
                              cat='Continuous')

Products = ['Apple', 'Orange']

for Location, Product in DF1.index:
    print(plp.lpSum(Production1[(Location, Product)] for Product in Products))
```

2. This 3 indexes case errors out.

```
import pandas as pd 
import pulp as plp

tuples1 = [('DE', 'Apple'),
          ('DE', 'Orange'),
          ('PA', 'Apple'),
          ('PA', 'Orange')]

index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1, names=["Location", "Product"])
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Count A': [12., 70., 30., 20.], 'Count B': [12., 70., 30., 20.]}, index=index1)

tuples2 = [('DE', 'Apple', 'Truck'),
           ('DE', 'Orange', 'Rail'),
           ('DE', 'Apple', 'Rail'),
           ('DE', 'Orange', 'Truck'),
           ('PA', 'Apple', 'Truck'),
           ('PA', 'Orange', 'Rail')]

index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2, names=["Location", "Product", "Mode"])
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Count A': [12., 70., 30., 20., 20., 40], 'Count B': [12., 70., 30., 20., 80., 30.]}, index=index2)

Production2 = plp.LpVariable.dicts("Production2",
                              ((Location, Product, Mode) for Location, Product, Mode in DF2.index),
                              lowBound=0,
                              cat='Continuous')

Modes = ['Truck', 'Rail']

for Location, Product in DF1.index:
    print(plp.lpSum(Production2[(Location, Product, Mode)] for Mode in Modes))
```

Comment: Assuming you have `import pulp` at the beginning, what you need is `pulp.lpSum()` method for summing over variable D. So, replace your `Production[(A,B,C,D)]` with `pulp.lpSum(Production[(A,B,C,D] for all D in your_d_index)`

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried this but it does not seem to work. See below. If I do  the below it works fine.   print(plp.lpSum(
    [Unmet_Demand[Month, Product, Customer] for Month, Product, Customer in Demand_DF1.index]
))     However, if i do this, it fails with a KeyError.     print(plp.lpSum(
    [Unmet_Demand[Month, Product, Customer] for Customer in Demand_DF1.index]
))

Comment: without knowing anything, I see that in both of those cases you loop over the same thing (`Demand_DF1.index`). If that index is comprised of 3 values of (Month, Product, Customer), then you can't use that to only iterate over Customer. In fact, `Customer` in `for Customer in Demand_DF1.index` is a tuple of (Month, Product, Customer). If you only want `Customer` you should use something else. For example, `customers = Demand_DF1['Customer'].unique()` and then use `for customer in customers` for your sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt responses. I confirmed it works when there are two  indexes but it does not seem to work for 3 or more indexes. Not sure what is going wrong at this point. I will continue to look into this and provide an update later.

Comment: I have provided more details about my testing with lpSum. Can one of you please try the codes and see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you say "it doesn't work" you're getting a `KeyError` which is expected in your 3-index model. Because you have 2 locations, 2 products, and 2 modes. Your 2-index tuple with product and location has all 4 indexes, but your 3-index tuple has 6, missing ('PA', 'Apple', 'Rail') and ('PA, 'Orange', 'Truck').

If this was a mistake, correct your 3-index tuple and your `KeyError` will be fixed. If not a mistake, then one way to fix this is to change your last line of code to the following, which checks if the key exists in `Production2` and if it's not, replaces it with 0:

```
print(plp.lpSum(Production2.get((Location, Product, Mode), 0) for Mode in Modes))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice solved my issue.